# Bootstrap span empty space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this easy code:

```
<div class="wrapper_big">
<div class="row-fluid grey">
<div class="span4">Will be logo</div>
<div class="span8">Will be menu</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.grey{background-color: #eeeeee;}
.wrapper_big {width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

and I have extra space after spans, see in picture here:
http://postimg.org/image/pt5khfcmv/

How remove it?

Update: [Fiddle with extra space](http://jsfiddle.net/mAt7p/embedded/result).

Comment: Please share us a jsfiddle because this code/markup is not helping..

Comment: I can't see an issue with the very little code you have provided http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/nBvew/

Comment: @vector i try paste code but my browser and jsfiddle show two other output, two span are in two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your css:

```
.span12 {
    min-height: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Tnx, work, why then don+t work when i put .span12 {min-height: none!important;} AFTER @import bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

in your custom css overwrite the row-fluid class

```
.row-fluid{ height:?px;  or  padding-bottom:0px }
```

or specifically for the wrapper_big:

```
.wrapper_big .row-fluid {height:?px;  or  padding-bottom:0px}
```

**Edited**

`@media (min-width: 1200px){
min-height:30px; }`

Copied from Element inspect from Google Chrome.

`.row-fluid`   has a `min-height`  property of `30px`

Remove this property and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `height` of `.grey` in both the links and see the difference.

[Link1](http://jsfiddle.net/nBvew/1/)

[Link2](http://jsfiddle.net/PZGdu/)