# empty space above bootstrap spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the empty area above the 4th span and replace it with the next span
Edit:   without adding new row 
[image]

here it the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Dzh5E/7/

```
<div class="main-app">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span6 lg-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
     </div>
</div>

.md-hieght {
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
.lg-hieght {
    height: 600px;
    background: blue;
}
.main-app {
    margin-left: 13%;
    margin-right: 13%;
}
```

Comment: you can goto boostrap site, and create your custom bootstrap css by reducing the vertical and horizontal gutter spaces to 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap span empty space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446996/bootstrap-span-empty-space)

Comment: @ManishMishra I don't know how to do this

Comment: @neshpro it doesn't work

Comment: hey, if you are using bootstrap 3.0, then go [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics), in the page, go to `Layout and Grid System` section, and then look for this textbox `@grid-gutter-width`, just set its default value(30px) to 0 or whatever you want, and generate

Answer (score 1):

You should add a new .row-fluid every 12 columns.

```
<div class="main-app">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span6 lg-hieght"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dzh5E/9/embedded/result/

Comment: I don't want to add new row

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to structure the html into two columns.  One for the short items that you wish to remove the space and one for the tall item.

You would have to adjust the margin's the way you wanted (or mentioned in the question's comments).  If you use this technique make sure to use more meaningful classes but I think by this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E569s/4/) is what you are looking for.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-app row-fluid">
    <div class="span9 short">
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
        <div class="span3 md-hieght"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 tall">
         <div class="span6 lg-hieght"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.short .span3 {
    /*Remove left margin and add a bottom and right*/
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: you reordered the spans and I want spans in that order

Comment: Is there a reason why you are opposed to reordering the spans or adding rows as mentioned in another answer?